# Rust borrowing with some object types and not others?

Tags: rust, borrowing

I am having a very difficult time understanding how borrowing works, and I can't for the life of me work out why these two cases are so different. The part that does work was inspired from https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-mutability-moving-and-borrowing-the-straight-dope/22166, the part that doesn't is what I am trying to achieve with a `Response` object from `reqwest`.

```
struct Player { name: String, age: u8, description: String }
impl Player {
    fn namefn(&self) -> &String {
        &self.name
    }
}

fn immutable_borrow_nok(borrowed: &reqwest::blocking::Response) -> Result<()> {
    // println!("I am some json, I don't work {:#?}", borrowed.text()); <-- if I get uncommented I won't compile
    Ok(())
}
fn immutable_borrow(borrowed: &Player) -> Result<()> {
    println!("I am {}, I've been immutably borrowed", borrowed.namefn());
    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> Result<()>{
    let our_player = Player { name: "Jones".to_string(), age: 25, description: "Just a happy guy.".to_string() };
    immutable_borrow(&our_player);
    println!("My name is {}, and I am being used after an immutable borrow", our_player.namefn());

    let res = reqwest::blocking::Client::new().post("http://httpbin.org/anything").send()?.error_for_status()?;
    immutable_borrow_nok(&res);
    println!("I am also some json but I *do* work... {:#?}", res.text());

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the `text` method [here](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.8/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.text) you can see that it consumes (moves) `self` after calling. So after calling `text` method you cannot use `Response` because it simply doesn't exist anymore.

But inside your `immutable_borrow_nok` function you have a reference to `Response`. `immutable_borrow_nok` does not own it. Values passed by the reference cannot be consumed. So `Response` can't be consumed (moved) inside `immutable_borrow_nok`.

If you really want to use `text` method inside `immutable_borrow_nok` you should define it like this:

```
// Response now owned by this function
fn immutable_owned_nok(owned: reqwest::blocking::Response) -> Result<()> {
    println!("I am some json, I don't work {:#?}", borrowed.text());
    Ok(())
}
```

But you should understand that after calling `immutable_owned_nok` you cannot use your `Response` anymore in your code.

Comment: And because of the NLL, the borrows for `immutable_borrow` and `immutable_borrow_nok` only span the function call (they're not necessary afterwards), which means the `println!` after `immutable_borrow_nok` can consume the value just fine. But if you try to use `res` after that, it will not compile.

Comment: @Masklinn That's just how borrowing has always worked, even before NLL. This code would work the same with lexical lifetimes.

Comment: Thanks @dmitry. So, for example in this case, my only option for getting the text of the response is to implement a method, say in a subclass of Response, that allows me to get the text without borrowing and then replace the existing implementation with my class? I'm just trying to work how much work is usually involved in the standard case when a "borrowing" method is not available for something.

Comment: I marked this as the answer as it was the only answer. A couple of points - "If you look at the text method here you can see that it moves self". That is far from trivial for a newcomer to rust!
It would also make it much clearer if someone who knows would edit Dmitry's answer for the third sentence - should that read "immutable_borrow_nok now owns it" or "immutable_borrow_nok does not own it"?